# get magento customer group id and magento group name from admin side

Tags: magento-1.7, php, admin

I need a script to show from admin side and export in XML Customer Group ID and Group Name.

This is the code to show Customer Group ID on front-end. But this is not working in back-end:

```
$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to load the customer model by the customer id, e.g.:

`$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);`

Then based on the customer model you can get the group id with `$customer->getGroupId()`

`Mage::helper('customer')->getGroups()` returns a list of groups excluding non-logged in one, based on it you can determine `customer_group_code` which will be the customer assigned group name

Comment: Zifius what code to use ? I trying this but not working.$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$customer->getGroupId() Mage::helper('customer')->getGroups();   Also i need to get custom attributes whatc I create. Order by, Purchase Order Number. How to get these custom attributes ?

Comment: @lew1s please post the code you have so far somewhere like GitHub gist, will be easier to go from there. Also the way you have created your attributes

Comment: Using Order Export tool by [link]https://www.wyomind.com/orders-export-tool-magento.html . I created two new attributes using Manage Customer Attributes from [link]  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-attributes.html which are "account number" and "rep code". With another extension [http://codecanyon.net/item/magento-order-attributes/8487808] I created Order attributes which are "Purchase number" and "Order by" . So I what to get these fields and show in my xml file.I trying to get the "customer group name" or ID and my custom attr.[link]http://pastebin.com/KS8qYGux

Comment: here is a documentation of export extension what I am using [link]https://www.wyomind.com/orders-export-tool-magento.html

Comment: @lew1s: in which extension you are trying to use the code I posted? it can't just work as is, has to be adapted and since the extension is not open source don't think you can share the code

Comment: I trying to use for "Order Export Tool" to get the customer Group ID and show in xml

Comment: @lew1s if you are not a developer I'd suggest contacting the extension vendor support or hiring a developer who could look into the code. Unfortunately it's not possible to help without seen the code in this case, sorry

Comment: @Zifius, does this work with the persistent cookie?

Comment: @Erfan sorry, can you clarify? you want to get customer I from cookie?

Comment: @Zifius, oops never mind - I meant to ask does `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()` work if you're actually logged out, but your persistent cookie is active? But I debugged it and it worked. There's an event observer in Mage_Persistent where it injects the customer_id and customer_group_id into the standard `customer/session`.

Comment: How to get `$customerId` in the first place??

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is:

For Customer Group Name:

```
<? return Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load({customer_group_id})->getCustomerGroupCode(); ?>
```

For two fields in Customer Account Information:

```
<? return Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load({customer_id})->getAccountNumber(); ?>
```

For the two field generated by Custom Order Attributes from CodeCanyon:

```
<? return Mage::getModel('glaceorderattr/attribute')->load({entity_id}, 'order_id')->getPurchaseOrderNumber(); ?>
```

I hope it helps somebody. THANKS TO @Zifius