# If else in Magento always return else value

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf

hi I have this If else statement in magento. It always landed on the else statement even though the value of the variable is 10.

Please I need all the help I can.

```
{{if var customer_group_id }} == 10
         Print CGD
{{else}}
         Print ICT  <------always landed here
 {{/if}}
```

Comment: I donno which code language is this, but you can try `{{if var customer_group_id == 10 }}
` instead `{{if var customer_group_id }} == 10`

Comment: what you have try above Can you specify this in detail.

Comment: @AnilSuthar - Either does not work

Comment: which code language is this ? Where have u written this code ? Which file ?

Comment: I have this PDF Invoice Plus extension installed. Then in the edit function of the pdf template you can actually write a code. When I wrote {{customer_group_id}} it shows the ID, then when I try to write {{customer_group_code}} it does not show anything so I thought of instead pushing to get the group_code I try to create an statement in which I can actully set group code staticly.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks like correct, but it doesn't work in transactionnal templates, you can use `{{if}}`, `{{depend}}` but just to check if the variable is **true** !. so to do you logic, comparison with other values etc... you have to do it in a block, you create this block then you insert it in your PDF template like this:

This code goes into the PDF template :

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='pdf/statement.phtml'}}
```

You create a file in :

```
app/design/frontend/{nameSpace}/{theme}/template/pdf/statement.phtml
```

Now you do your stuff inside something like this:

```
<?php
if ( Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() )
{
    $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    if ($groupId == 10)
    {
        echo $this->__('CGD');
    } else {
       echo $this->__('ICT');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me out sir.

app/design/frontend/default/default/template/pdf/statement.phtml

and inside It I pasted the code you gave.

Then I edited my PDF Template and put that block thing but nothing happened.

Comment: I did this`$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    if ($groupId == 10)
    {
        echo $this->__('CGD');
    } else {
       echo $this->__('ICT');`  But it is always landing on the ICT i cannot get the $groupId it always return a 0 value

Comment: For information, `$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()‌​;`means that you get the customer group id from session, so if the customer is not logged you will not get it ! this is why you return nothing with `if ( Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() ) ...`
if you are sending your PDF without the user being logged in, you can get the groupID not from session. look this exemple : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55736/get-magento-customer-group-id-and-magento-group-name-from-admin-side

Comment: How do I pass the customer_group_id from my PDF Template to my phtml?

Comment: `echo Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load({customer_group_id})->getCustomerGroupCode();
    if ($groupId == 10)
    {
        echo $this->__('CGD');
    } else {
       echo $this->__('ICT');
    }`

How do I pass Customer_Group_Id

Comment: No, `this ->load({customer_group_id})`  doesn't work, use instead `$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId)->getGroupId();`
Is a PDF of what you are you generating this PDF and in wich case ?

Comment: I'm generating invoice PDF using a magento extension. Custom PDF. How Do I transfer the customerid from HTML template to my phtml.